# i want to update the field of opportunity on account

Tags: visual-workflow, salesforce-flow

I have a field called close date on opportunity i want to update last close won opportunity date on account custom field ,i Tried using record trigger flow on Account object but still not getting the expected output

Comment: Welcome to SSE !! Can you share the flow which you tried and also share the error you are facing  by editing the post

Answer (score 1):

You should create a record triggered flow on the Opportunity object.

You will test if the *IsWon* field on the Opportunity record has been updated to *true*, and if yes, then you can update the date on the Account record, by setting the current date.